# How to connect Dialowflow and Messenger

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-cx

I have been trying to connect my chat bot from dialog flow to the messenger of my Facebook page and i can't.

I already try with an app from Meta Developers but when i try to connect the Webhook whit the URL from dialog flow the app shows a message where explain that i can't connect the webhook unless the app is active besides i can't active the app 'cause the page requires a lot of information. I need to integrate the chat bot to my messenger without another platform and that it can answer message.